# Live streaming RTMP to HTML5

Tags: html, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I have a `RTMP` live stream coming from `Unreal Media Server` that I need to display on a HTML5 page with `<video>` tag. So far I am thinking of using ffmpeg libraries to transcode the stream with H.264 codec and output it to a .mp4 file and then access it through http protocol like this:  `http://ip_addr/output_from_ffmpeg.mp4` I am, however, uncertain if this would play the whole output file from the beginning or stream it live. My current ffmpeg command for transcoding the stream is:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://IP_addr_of_rtmp_stream:5119/live/Roulette -c:v libx264 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -g 50 output.mp4
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have also read in the docs that ffserver is able to achieve this but windows build is unavailable for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) (which uses FFmpeg) for transcoding the RTMP stream with `H.264` codec and displaying it in `.ogg` format with built-in http server of VLC. Also I started another instance of VLC for `HLS` streaming for Apple based devices. Here are the two commands for `H.264` and `HLS` respectively (note: I did this on windows, and used `wamp` for HLS streaming as VLC does not provide the means for transport in this case):

```
vlc.exe -I dummy rtmp://_ip_addr_of_the_rtmp_stream :network-caching=0 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=512,scale=1,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8181/stream.ogg} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep

vlc.exe -I dummy rtmp://_ip_addr_of_the_rtmp_stream :network-caching=0 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=500, venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=30,ref=1}, aenc=none} :std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=5, index=C:\wamp\www\stream.m3u8, index-url=http://_ip_addr_of_your_web_server/stream-########.ts}, mux=ts{use-key-frames}, dst=C:\wamp\www\stream-########.ts}"
```

Then in html page simply:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://_ip_addr_of_your_web_server/stream.m3u8" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
  <source src="http://_ip_addr_of_your_web_server:8181/stream.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Further reading:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone/

Comment: This won't work on Internet Explorer unfortunately, in case you target all browsers/devices.

Comment: In case of IE and some others, I would recommend fallback to flash/flv

Comment: Flash fallback requires a flash web player, it won't work with just HTML5 tags.

Comment: I never said it would. But adding the necessary code is almost trivial, that is, if you do consider flash as a solution in whole

Comment: can you share me the server configuration. which server you are using for this?

Comment: @vijayky88 I used Windows Server 2012 with 32 GB RAM. But you can make it work on almost all modern OS-es that support ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot live stream using the `mp4` format and you cannot live stream using only HTML5 tags. Your command records the stream in a static `mp4` file to be served via HTTP progressive download.

`RTMP` requires a Flash player. Alternatives include `HLS` and a web-player that supports Flash fallback for desktops (eg. Clappr, JWPlayer, Flowplayer) or `DASH` via Media Source Extensions (MSE) on the browsers that support it.

Answer (score 1):

Unreal Media Server v12 (released Sep 15 2016) supports exactly what you need.
You don't need to transcode anything. The same broadcast that was playing via RTMP, now can be played in HTML5 video tag.